# How to create a standard WP Page that has the same url as an archive

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

I've tried to Google this but to no avail. I'm a newbie at programming but I can say I'm adept at configuring WP - pretty please, please bear with me. :)

I have a CUSTOM_TAXONOMY that when viewed, the archive's url is example.com/custom_taxonomy/actual_taxonomy/.

Since I wanted my posts to have this new custom taxonomy's slug in all my post urls, I went to Settings >> Permalinks in WP dashboard and set it to "Custom Structure" of example.com/%custom_taxonomy%/%postname%/, I am able to actually get my goal of having standard posts with that url scheme.

However, when I was about to create a wp page with url: example.com/actual_taxonomy to properly display the archives for my custom taxonomy with some few added designs, it seems that example.com/custom_taxonomy is turned into an auto-archive, with the same layout as the one in the second paragraph above.

I really wanted to create my own page and set the url as example.com/actual_taxonomy, however it's already there because I've set it in Settings >> Permalinks. Is there any way to avoid this issue? Much thanks guys!

**TL;DR**

I have the "Custom Structure" of example.com/%area%/%postname%/ in Settings >> Permalinks.

So my standard posts have this URL: sitename.com/"area"/"postname"

And because of what I've done in Settings>Permalinks, my taxonomy pages have these URLs: sitename.com/california/ and sitename.com/area/california (where "california" is the taxonomy page)

Now I want to create a new "page" with the same slug, california.

I can create a new "california" page easily, however, when I go to sitename.com/california/ the taxonomy archive is displayed -- instead of the newly created page.

My question: Is there a way to "override" the default priority of taxonomy over a page? I'd like to show page because I will have control over it -- I can customize, add more content, and change them easily (plus, pages are going to help me structure my site better)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What are you using in order to create the Taxonomy, can you drop that code in here??

Comment: Is this a page with a page template that lists out all the terms in the taxonomy? How are you avoiding clashes between post slugs and term slugs in URLs?

Comment: Well, I didn't fully understand what you want to acomplish, but I think something will help you is make a simple route map in a txt file and post here like: mysite/taxonomy/term => archive.php, mysite/page_slug => page.php for example. And which part of this routing you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJones thanks! i use CPT UI plugin to create the taxonomy.

$args = array(
  "public" => true,
  "publicly_queryable" => true,
  "hierarchical" => true,
  "show_ui" => true,
  "show_in_menu" => true,
  "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
  "query_var" => true,
  "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'area', 'with_front' => true, ),
  "show_admin_column" => true,
  "show_in_rest" => true,
  "rest_base" => "area",
  "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
  "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
  );
 register_taxonomy( "area", array( "post", "blog" ), $args );

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks! yes correct. Currently I cannot avoid any clashes between post slugs and term slugs in URLs, hence this issue I'm having.

Comment: @LucasVendramini thanks and so sorry about that, I have edited my original question above (Please see TL;DR section in bold) for the much clearer question. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bacorrito, %area% is a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Please, don't mess with custom structure, I think you should try to solve the problem using the normal routing of WordPress first. Use the 'post name' option (saved my life for once and for all). I guess that will solve your problem. Well, You said area/california is redirecting to another template other than page.php, it's redirecting to taxonomy.php? Maybe that could help you: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @LucasVendramini Thanks! %area% is a custom taxonomy.The reason why I'm doing all these is to make it look like a multisite but it's actually a single install. eg. for posts that are appropriate for california, the post url is site.com/california/postname. And then I wanted to have a DEDICATED page for posts tagged with "California", so that I can customize, add more content, and change them easily in contrast with just having the usual archives page. What are your thoughts on this? Is there a better way to achieve this using the normal WP routing (just the "post name" option)? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Bacorrito, The post page option will handle everything for you. You need only to understand the template hierarchy and you are done. I guess you could use the parent post feature of wordpress, you can put a page as parent of another. So the slug will be parent/child, hope that helps! You want something like area/california/los-angeles? If so, will be taxonomy/parent_page/child_page

Comment: Thanks @LucasVendramini for your suggestions. I guess it all boils down to following standard WP process and edit the template files instead. By the way, the reason I have %area%/%postname%/ in Settings >> Permalinks is because something like area/california/los-angeles sounds a bit off. For example, site.com/los-angeles with its own dedicated page would look/sound more authoritative than a url that's very long. Looks like I need to decide which step to move forward. Much thanks for your suggestions, really appreciate!